# Can we resolve two variables at a time in CNF resolution

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

Are we allowed to resolve two variables at a time in CNF resolution?

For e.g. we have:

what will be the resolution of: $(P \lor \lnot Q \lor R) \land (\lnot P \lor Q \lor R)$

and what will be the resolution of: $(P \lor \lnot Q \lor R) \land (\lnot P \lor Q)$

Thanks, Hakid

Comment: See the [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique): "If the resulting clause contains complementary literals, it is discarded (as a tautology)." Thus, resolving $(P∨¬Q∨R)$ with $(¬P∨Q∨R)$ we get $(Q∨¬Q∨R) \equiv \text {TRUE}$.

Comment: What you have to understand is how the rule works: when we apply Resolution rule to e.g. $\{ P,Q \}, \{ \lnot P, R \}$ we are really applying Distributivity to the Conjunction of the two clauses: $(P \lor Q) \land (\lnot P \lor R)$. If you "develop" it, you will find $(P \lor \lnot P) \land \ldots$. The first Conjunct is equiv to TRUE, and thus we can delete it.

Comment: If instead we arrive at the two clauses $\{ P \}$ and $\{ \lnot P \}$, what we get is $P \land \lnot P$, i.e. $\bot$ (a contradiction) that is unsatisfiable. Thus, when we produce the empty clause (i.e. $\bot$) the conclusion is that the initial set of clauses is *unsatisfiable*.

Answer (score 1):

No!  Absolutely not!

Consider: You have $\{A, B \}$ and $\{\neg A, \neg B \}$

If you could resolve two at a time this would result in the empty clause $\{ \}$, which would suggest that the orginal clauses are not satisfiable. But clearly they are, e.g. set $A$ to True and $B$ to False.